# Unable to submit form when using Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm unable to submit form when using Jquery validation.
when I submit, the form is reloaded again and it is unable to perform other actions like sending mail, generating alerts, etc which are given in another php page

Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form" id="contactform">
    <p class="requiredNote">
        <em>*</em> Denotes a required field.
    </p>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name" class="three columns ">Name of Person: <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required seven columns" role="input" aria-required="true"  size="30"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label class="three columns ">Name of Company <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="required seven columns" role="input" aria-required="true" size="30"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="message" class="three columns ">Address<em>*</em></label>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="" name="message" id="message" class="required seven columns " role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="phno1" class="three columns " >Phone no <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="tel" name="phno1" id="phno1" value="" class="required seven columns" role="textbox" aria-required="true"  size=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="phno2" class="three columns ">Mobile no <em>*</em></label>
        <input type="tel" name="phno2" id="phno2" value="" class="required seven columns" role="input" aria-required="true" size="33"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="email" class="three columns ">Email: <em>*</em></label>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="required email seven columns" id="email" value="" size="50" aria-required="true" role="input" />
    </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <label class="three columns " >Requirement Type:<em>*</em> </label>
        <select class="required  three columns" role="input" aria-required="true" name="reqsize" id="req">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
            <option  value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
            <option  value="Land">Land</option>
            <option  value="BTS">BTS</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label  for="prefloc" class="three columns " >Preferred Location:<em>*</em></label>
        <select class="required three columns" role="input" aria-required="true" name="prefloc" id="prefloc">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option value="All" >All</option>
            <option value="Alappuzha" >Alappuzha</option>
            <option value="Alleppey" >Alleppey</option>
            <option value="Aroor" >Aroor</option>
            <option value="Mannar" >Mannar</option>
            <option value="Cheranallur" >Cheranallur</option>
            <option value="Ernakulam" >Ernakulam</option>
            <option value="Aluva" >Aluva</option>
            <option value="Angamaly" >Angamaly</option>
            <option value="Chelavannor" >Chelavannor</option>
            <option value="Chittoor" >Chittoor</option>
            <option value="Chottanikkara" >Chottanikkara</option>
            <option value="Collectorate Kochi" >Collectorate Kochi</option>
            <option value="Eloor" >Eloor</option>
            <option value="Ernakulam City" >Ernakulam City</option>
            <option value="Banerji Road" >Banerji Road</option>
            <option value="Ernakulam North" >Ernakulam North</option>
            <option value="Ernakulam South" >Ernakulam South</option>
            <option value="MG Road" >MG Road</option>
            <option value="Rajaji Road" >Rajaji Road</option>
            <option value="Kundanoor" >Kundanoor</option>
            <option value="Kumaranasan road" >Kumaranasan road</option>
            <option value="Kochi" >Kochi</option>
            <option value="Edappally" >Edappally</option>
            <option value="Kakkanad" >Kakkanad</option>
            <option value="Kaloor" >Kaloor</option>
            <option value="Elamakkara" >Elamakkara</option>
            <option value="Vyttila" >Vyttila</option>
            <option value="Vennala" >Vennala</option>
            <option value="Vaduthala" >Vaduthala</option>
            <option value="Vallarpadam" >Vallarpadam</option>
            <option value="Chembumukku" >Chembumukku</option>
            <option value="Gandhi Nagar" >Gandhi Nagar</option>
            <option value="Irumpanam" >Irumpanam</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label  for="prefcity" class="three columns " >Preferred City:<em>*</em></label>
        <select class="required three columns" role="input" aria-required="true" name="prefcity" id="prefcity">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="Ernakulam">Ernakulam</option>
            <option   value="Kottayam ">Kottayam </option>
            <option   value="Kollam">Kollam</option>
            <option   value="Thrissur">Thrissur</option>
            <option value="Thiruvananthapuram">Thiruvananthapuram</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="size" class="three columns " >Sqft details</label>
        <input name="sqft" type="text" id="sqft" class="three columns"/>
    </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <label for="floor" class="three columns "  >Preferred Floors: <em>*</em></label>
        <select class="required  three columns" role="input" aria-required="true" name="floor" id="preffloor">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="1">1</option>
            <option  value="2">2</option>
            <option  value="3">3</option>
            <option  value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label  for="shell" class="three columns "  >Shell Type:<em>*</em></label>
        <select class="required three columns" role="input" aria-required="true" name="shell" id="shell">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="Bare">Bare</option>
            <option   value="Warm or Plug">Warm or Plug</option>
            <option   value="play">play</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label  for="car" class="three columns " >Required car parks:<em>*</em></label>
        <select  name="car" class="three columns" id="car">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="20">20</option>
            <option   value="30">30</option>
            <option   value="40">40</option>
            <option   value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="" class="three columns ">Required power:<em>*</em> </label>
        <select  name="power" class="three columns" id="power">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="35 KVA">35 KVA</option>
            <option  value="45 KVA">45 KVA</option>
            <option  value="55 KVA">55 KVA</option>
            <option  value="65 KVA">65 KVA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="" class="three columns ">Rental Range per sft:<em>*</em> </label>
        <select  name="sftrange" class="three columns" id="sftrange">
            <option  value="">-------- select --------</option>
            <option  value="1000 sft-1500 sft">1000 sft-1500 sft</option>
            <option  value="2000 sft-2500 sft">2000 sft-2500 sft</option>
            <option  value="3000 sft-3500 sft">3000 sft-3500 sft</option>
            <option  value="4000 sft-4500 sft">4000 sft-4500 sft</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="" class="three columns ">Expected Time frame to acquire the poperty:</label>
        <input type="text" name="expt" id="" value=""  size="" class="seven columns" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="sugg" class="three columns ">Specifications, if any:</label>
        <textarea name="sugg" cols="" rows="1" class="seven columns"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label  for=" " class="three columns">Captcha:<em>*</em></label>
        <img src="php_captcha.php" border="0"  />
        <input name="captcha_value" type="text" id="captcha_value"  placeholder="Enter Captcha"/>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative" class="form-row" >
        <p style="position:absolute;left:22%;top:4%">
            <input type="image" value="Send Message" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" src="assets/img/submit_btn.png" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

validate1.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var jVal = {
    'contactname' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="contactInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var contactInfo = $('#contactInfo');
        var ele = $('#contactname');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        contactInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        if (ele.val().length < 6) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            contactInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; at least 6 characters').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            contactInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    'subject' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="subjectInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var subjectInfo = $('#subjectInfo');
        var ele = $('#subject');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        subjectInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        if (ele.val().length < 4) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            subjectInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; at least 4 characters').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            subjectInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'message' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="nameInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var nameInfo = $('#nameInfo');
        var ele = $('#message');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        nameInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        if (ele.val().length < 25) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            nameInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; at least 25 characters').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            nameInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    'phno1' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="phnInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var phnInfo = $('#phnInfo');
        var ele = $('#phno1');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        phnInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        var patt = /^[0-9-+]+$/i;

        if (!patt.test(ele.val())) {

            jVal.errors = true;
            phnInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; type phone no. in correct format').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');

        }
        if (ele.val().length < 10 || ele.val().length > 12) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            phnInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; type phone no. in correct format').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            phnInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'phno2' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="birthInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var birthInfo = $('#birthInfo');
        var ele = $('#phno2');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        birthInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        var patt = /^[0-9-+]+$/i;

        if (!patt.test(ele.val())) {

            jVal.errors = true;
            birthInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; type phone no. in correct format').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');

        }
        if (ele.val().length < 10 || ele.val().length > 12) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            birthInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; type phone no. in correct format').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            birthInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'email' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="emailInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var emailInfo = $('#emailInfo');
        var ele = $('#email');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        emailInfo.css({
            top : pos.top - 3,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        var patt = /^.+@.+[.].{2,}$/i;

        if (!patt.test(ele.val())) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            emailInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; give me a valid email adress, ok?').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            emailInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'req' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="genderInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var genderInfo = $('#genderInfo');
        var ele = $('#req');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        genderInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });

        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            genderInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            genderInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'prefloc' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="preflocInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var preflocInfo = $('#preflocInfo');

        var ele = $('#prefloc');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        preflocInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="prefloc"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            preflocInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            preflocInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'prefcity' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="prefcityInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var prefcityInfo = $('#prefcityInfo');

        var ele = $('#prefcity');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        prefcityInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="prefcity"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            prefcityInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            prefcityInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'preffloor' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="preffloorInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var preffloorInfo = $('#preffloorInfo');

        var ele = $('#preffloor');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        preffloorInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="preffloor"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            preffloorInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            preffloorInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    'shell' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="shellInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var shellInfo = $('#shellInfo');

        var ele = $('#shell');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        shellInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="shell"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            shellInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            shellInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    'car' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="carInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var carInfo = $('#carInfo');

        var ele = $('#car');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        carInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="car"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            carInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            carInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'power' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="powerInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var powerInfo = $('#powerInfo');

        var ele = $('#power');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        powerInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="power"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            powerInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            powerInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'sftrange' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="sftrangeInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var sftrangeInfo = $('#sftrangeInfo');

        var ele = $('#sftrange');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        sftrangeInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 25
        });
        //if($('select[name="sftrange"]:selected').length === 0)
        if (ele.length == 0 || $(ele).val() == "") {
            jVal.errors = true;
            sftrangeInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; please select your choice').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            sftrangeInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },
    'captcha_value' : function() {

        $('body').append('<div id="captchaInfo" class="info"></div>');

        var captchaInfo = $('#captchaInfo');
        var ele = $('#captcha_value');
        var pos = ele.offset();

        captchaInfo.css({
            top : pos.top + 1,
            left : pos.left + ele.width() + 15
        });

        if (ele.val().length < 6) {
            jVal.errors = true;
            captchaInfo.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').html('&larr; Please enter given captcha').show();
            ele.removeClass('normal').addClass('wrong');
        } else {
            captchaInfo.removeClass('error').addClass('correct').html('&radic;').show();
            ele.removeClass('wrong').addClass('normal');
        }
    },

    /*'sendIt' : function() {
        if (!jVal.errors) {
            $('#contactform').submit();
        }
    }*/
};

// ====================================================== //

$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var obj = $.browser.webkit ? $('body') : $('html');
    obj.animate({
        scrollTop : $('#contactform').offset().top
    }, 750, function() {
        jVal.errors = false;
        jVal.contactname();
        jVal.subject();
        jVal.message();
        jVal.phno1();
        jVal.phno2();
        jVal.email();
        jVal.req();
        jVal.prefloc();
        jVal.prefcity();
        jVal.preffloor();
        jVal.shell();
        jVal.car();
        jVal.power();
        jVal.sftrange();
        jVal.captcha_value();
        jVal.sendIt();
    });
    return false;
});

$('#contactname').change(jVal.contactname);
$('#subject').change(jVal.subject);
$('#message').change(jVal.message);
$('#phno1').change(jVal.phno1);
$('#phno2').change(jVal.phno2);
$('#email').change(jVal.email);
$('input[name="req"]').change(jVal.req);
$('select[name="prefloc"]').change(jVal.prefloc);
$('select[name="prefcity"]').change(jVal.prefcity);
$('select[name="preffloor"]').change(jVal.preffloor);
$('select[name="shell"]').change(jVal.shell);
$('select[name="car"]').change(jVal.car);
$('select[name="power"]').change(jVal.power);
$('select[name="sftrange"]').change(jVal.sftrange);
$('#captcha_value').change(jVal.captcha_value);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your sendit function is inside of a comment block. Is this causing you the problem? Because now at this moment the form is not being submitted?

Also if you uncomment it be sure that jVal.errors exists because I cannot find it (or I'm reading over it).

Comment: I tried after removing the comment of sendit function. But still it is not working.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly is your problem? Does the jquery validation works? Or do you only have problems with submitting the form? Because when you don't want to reload the page when submitting, you'll need to work with ajax.

Comment: Also by running your code I had an error on this line 'var obj = $.browser.webkit ? $('body') : $('html');'. I've changed this to '$('body').animate({' and now it's working fine for me. See this fiddle in action: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z2x4/

Comment: Actually jquery validation is working. but i'm unable submit this form. After submitting, I have to send mail and some other actions also. when submitting, this page gets reloaded, but further actions are not performed.